# Initial staking window

Tags: staking

We know the following:

- Upon mainnet launch, all the tokens are staked (50% CPU, 50% bandwidth).
- Staking for RAM & Bandwidth is effective at least for 3 days.
- A network needs 15% vote of all tokens to be considered the mainnet
- Only after 15% of tokens have voted, "unstaking" is possible

However, I wasn't able to find any information is the three days counted from the genesis block, or when 15% voting threshold is achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the threshold is achieved.  This can be easily confirmed by a post from Thomas Cox (VP of Product for block.one) entitled "Magic 15%-Unlocking the EOSIO Blockchain"

Here, Cox states "And even after we hit 15% and the “unstake” command becomes available, it takes three days for unstaking of tokens used for CPU or bandwidth.
So relax. Even if we hit 15% by the time you get this email, you’ll need to issue “unstake” before you can sell anything. And then you’ll need to wait 3 days."

In summary, the unstake command is not available until the 15% consensus is achieved.  Thereafter, you would still "need to wait 3 days."

https://medium.com/@thomas.cox_39839/magic-15-unlocking-the-eosio-blockchain-91ec54f7b48d